# Are Office Online Server patches still cumulative?

Tags: patching, office-online-server

The last 'official' release of OfficeOnlineServer is from November 2018. Since then, some patches have been tagged as `Security fixes`, e.g.

[KB4475511](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58358) - Jun 2019
[KB4462169](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58296) - May 2019

Are those patches still cumulative? So can i move from November 2018 to June 2019 directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all OOS patches are also Public Updates, thus cumulative. Don't forget you need to be on the latest OOS release (Nov 2018 at the time of this post) to be able to install updates.